# Angular Material Textbox losing value on page change in a mat table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have an Angular Material table in which I am populating data. I have an input box as one of the columns in the table to accept a value from the user. The table looks like this -

[image: initial table look]

Since the records can be more so I am using mat-paginator for pagination as well. The problem I am facing is this - When I enter a value in the text box(like 12 or 10 in the above screenshot) and then change the page and come back to the initial page, the already entered values are lost from all the text boxes(#screenshot 2 & 3).

[image: Page change]

[image: Back to initial page]
How can I persist the already entered values in the text boxes even after the page is changed?

**HTML template**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" style="width: 100%">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Value Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element.value }}

        <input
          type="number"
          matInput
          placeholder="Enter qty.."
          min="1"
          (change)="valueInput($event, element)"
          [value]="element.value"
        />
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
    showFirstLastButtons
  ></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Typescript -**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'value'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  value: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', value: '' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He', value: '' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li', value: '' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be', value: '' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B', value: '' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C', value: '' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N', value: '' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O', value: '' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F', value: '' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne', value: '' },
  { position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na', value: '' },
  { position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg', value: '' },
  { position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al', value: '' },
  { position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si', value: '' },
  { position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P', value: '' },
  { position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S', value: '' },
  { position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl', value: '' },
  { position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar', value: '' },
  { position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K', value: '' },
  { position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca', value: '' },
];
```

Comment: can you try updating your with these values, and if it works, ill explain why:

on component create `valueMap = {}`; then in HTML, instead of input having `[value]="element.value"` make it have `[value]="inputMap[element.position]"` (using position as Id), and `(change)="($event, inputMap[element.position])"`. I think what you are facing is the fact that the table only renders what its shown, and you are saving state on the element, so when not shown, it loses state.

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli thanks
tried this one, doesn`t seem to work. I get what you are trying to do here. Will try this out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `[value]="element.value"` on the input it will not bind the input value to the element it will do the opposite. So the value of the input is not affected to the element value attribute and when you change the page the state of the input is lost.

**To save the state to the element** attribute you can use `[(ngModel)]="element.value"` instead and you should also remove {{ element.value }} or else it will display the value twice first in {{ element.value }} and second on the input

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <input
                type="number"
                matInput
                placeholder="Enter qty.."
                min="1"
                [(ngModel)]="element.value"
                (change)="valueInput($event, element)"
        />
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Mohammed this seems to work, thanks for this. For everyone else facing the same issue, refrain from using conditions in binding the ngModel. This solution works otherwise.